# Bootstrap select dropdown not rendering viewbag items

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

For some reason my list is showing up disabled I am trying to use bootstrap-select here

https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

This is my code that gets the items there is nothing wrong with it as 3 items exist in the view bag

```
 public void GetStandardLookups(int LookupGroupId) {
        List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var items = _context.StandardLookups.Where(w => w.LookupGroup == LookupGroupId).ToList();
        foreach (var item in items) {
            SelectListItem listItem = new SelectListItem();
            listItem.Text = item.LookupText;
            listItem.Value = item.Id.ToString();
            listItems.Add(listItem);
        }
        if(LookupGroupId == Constants.EnforcmentType)
        ViewBag.EnforceMentTypesList = listItems;
        if (LookupGroupId == Constants.EnforcmentCategory)
            ViewBag.EnforcmentCategoryList = listItems;
   
 }
```

I Create the dropdown as such after storing in the view bag on the controller action of edit. But when I look at the raw html all i have is. This is three rows of data in the database that should be pulling through and I debugged my code and it is getting three items in list Items.

[image]

> Nothing selected

I am initializing my bootstrap select as follows

```
$(function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

})
```

I am producing my drop down as follows.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Enf_Type, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EnforceMentTypesList, String.Empty, new { @class = "selectpicker form-control" })
```

My Edit action

Comment: It's a little bit confusing. You're able to add the 3 rows on your viewbag but your dropdown list is disabled?

Comment: Correct there is nothing to show in the drop down when i take off selectpicker it works just fine but without the bootstrap select styling

Comment: is the dropdown disabled or just empty?

Comment: its shows the words nothing to select and is disabled non clickable but when i remove the class selectpicker it works. I want to style the picker in the way bootstrap-select does

Comment: that's weird that it's disabled. Maybe there's something on your js code that disables the drop down.

Comment: @RodTalingting why would there be when i remove that class it works

Answer (score 0):

I did a test using same [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) you share with testing data, which work as expected.

> its shows the words nothing to select and is disabled non clickable

Please check if the html source of **dropdown-toggle** button with CSS class `'disabled'` like below.

```
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle disabled btn-light bs-placeholder" data-toggle="dropdown" role="combobox" aria-owns="bs-select-1" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="false" data-id="Enf_Type" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true" title="Nothing selected"><div class="filter-option"><div class="filter-option-inner"><div class="filter-option-inner-inner">Nothing selected</div></div> </div></button>
```

And if rendered `<select>` element with `disabled` attribute.

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Enf_Type field is required." disabled="disabled" id="Enf_Type" name="Enf_Type" tabindex="-98"><option value="">
```

You can try to [programmatically enable a selectpicker](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh) with following code snippet.

```
$('.selectpicker').prop('disabled', false);

$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

[image]

Comment: I am using the admin lte site to theme my site and it refusing to work there at all it will refuse to drop down

Comment: If you just apply bootstrap-select to a specific view page without using other client-side css&js framework (not specifying `_Layout`), does it work well? It seems be incompatible/conflicting with other css&js frameworks.